# Compiler error after deploying to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, compiler-errors

I have a cloud service which has a web role and a worker role, using queues, storage and tables. I published it to Azure and everything seemed fine. When I click on the web app URL I get the following error:

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -2146232576.

If I deploy the web app locally everything works fine! Can someone help me please?
I tried looking online but I couldn't find a solution and I'm very new to this.

Comment: What's your Roslyn compiler version? If you are using Roslyn compiler 2.0+, you need to install .net framework 4.6+ on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing a "Publish" directly from Visual Studio?

Try nuking the web root and publishing again. It's likely due to file conflicts.

https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\home\site\wwwroot' | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Worked for me... thanks for saving me two hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: This worked for me once but again the same issue arose and not able to fix this time